# Swift 3 - Remember the selection made

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have two questions. Need your help badly for swift3.

In my app, I am asking Users to set the Province from picker list. Once user selected the province, I want to store the selection somewhere so when user kill the app and comes back, they dont have to select the province again.

Second thing: pretty much same as first. I am letting user to select the background color they want.

Let say user has set the background color as Black and when they kill the app, what should I do to keep the background color black only or whatever they have set.

Please advise.

Comment: `(NS)UserDefaults` can be used for that.

Comment: See [`UserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults). It's not the right place to store general model information (perhaps things like CoreData is better for that), but for basic information about default colors and region, `UserDefaults` will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

For set:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(province, forKey: "province")
```

For retrieve:

```
province = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "province")
```